# Как убрать меню, оставшееся от предыдущего фрагмента?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Я добавляю фрагменты в стек. Фрагментов 2 вида: у одного есть меню (ArticleFragment), у другого - нет (WebViewFragment). Проблема в том, что при добавлении фрагмента без меню поверх фрагмента с меню, меню старого фрагмента остаётся видимым. Новые фрагменты я добавляю в адаптере списка, список находится во фрагменте ArticleFragment.

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Fragment fragment;
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager();
        if(pos == mFirstExtraLinkPosition){
            fragment = WebViewFragment.newInstance(part.getContentLink()); //без меню
        }else {
            fragment = ArticleFragment.newInstance(null, part.getText(), part.getContentLink()); //с меню
        }
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.article_fragment_host, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }
```

Код фрагмента без меню:

```
public class WebViewFragment extends Fragment {
private static final String URI = "uri";
private WebView mWebView;
private Toolbar mToolbar;
private AppCompatActivity mActionBar;
private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
private Uri mUri;
private String mLink;

public static WebViewFragment newInstance(String uri){
    WebViewFragment webViewFragment = new WebViewFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable(URI, uri);
    webViewFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return webViewFragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mLink = (String) getArguments().getSerializable(URI);
    mUri = Uri.parse(mLink);
    setHasOptionsMenu(false);
}

@Nullable
@Override
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.webview_fragment_layout, container,false);
    mToolbar = v.findViewById(R.id.web_toolbar);
    mProgressBar = v.findViewById(R.id.webview_progress_bar);
    mWebView = v.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mActionBar = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
    mActionBar.setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    mToolbar.setTitle(mLink);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView webView, int newProgress){
            if (newProgress == 100) {
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mProgressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
            }
        }
        public void onReceivedTitle(WebView webView, String title) {
            mToolbar.setTitle(webView.getTitle());
        }
    });
    mWebView.loadUrl(mUri.toString());
    return v;
}
```

}

Код фрагмента с меню:

```
public class ArticleFragment extends Fragment {

private Toolbar mToolbar;
private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
private Article mArticle;
private ArrayList<ArticlePart> mArticleParts;
private ArticleRecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;
private AppCompatActivity mActionBar;

private String mArticleTitle, mArticleDate, mArticleLink;

private static final String ARG_ARTICLE_DATE = "article_date";
private static final String ARG_ARTICLE_TITLE = "article_title";
private static final String ARG_ARTICLE_LINK = "article_link";

private boolean mSaved = false;

public static ArticleFragment newInstance(String date, String title, String link){
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable(ARG_ARTICLE_DATE, date);
    bundle.putSerializable(ARG_ARTICLE_TITLE, title);
    bundle.putSerializable(ARG_ARTICLE_LINK, link);
    ArticleFragment articleFragment = new ArticleFragment();
    articleFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return articleFragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mArticleTitle = (String) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_ARTICLE_TITLE);
    mArticleDate = (String)getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_ARTICLE_DATE);
    mArticleLink = (String)getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_ARTICLE_LINK);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_fragment, container, false);
    mToolbar = v.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_article);
    mProgressBar = v.findViewById(R.id.progressbar_article);
    mProgressBar.setMax(100);
    mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    mRecyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.article_recyclerview);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    mArticleParts = new ArrayList<>();
    mArticle = new Article(mArticleDate, mArticleTitle, mArticleLink);
    mActionBar = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
    mActionBar.setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    if(mActionBar.getSupportActionBar() != null){
        mActionBar.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
    mActionBar.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    if(mArticleDate != null){
        mActionBar.setTitle(mArticleDate);
    }else {
        mActionBar.setTitle("...");
    }
    mAdapter = new ArticleRecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), mArticleTitle, mArticleParts);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    new FetchPartsTask(mArticleLink, this).execute();
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear();
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.article_menu, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.share:
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.share_button_hint, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.star:
            if(!mSaved){
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.added_to_favs, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                item.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_favorited));
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.deleted_from_favs, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                item.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_not_favorited));
            }
            mSaved = !mSaved;
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Совершил глупую ошибку: надо было просто добавить вызов метода setHasOptionsMenu(true); в методе onCreate. и переопределить метод onCreateOptionsMenu, добавив в его реализацию строчку menu.clear();